# Take argument of type Iterator with Item type parametrized by impl type constraint

Tags: types, syntax, rust, traits

I have a generic struct:

```
pub struct Smth<T: Copy> {
    data: Vec<T>
}
```

How can I implement a method with parameter `p` being some iterator with item type `T`?

Something like this, but working (look at `add_iter` method) :)

```
impl<T: Copy> Smth<T> {
    fn new(data: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        Smth { data }
    }

    fn add(&mut self, item: T) {
        self.data.push(item);
    }

    fn add_iter<I: Iterator>(&mut self, iter: I)
        where I::Item: T  // <-- Here is the problem
    {
        for item in iter {
           self.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried `where I::Item: Copy`, but that wouldn't work either.

Comment: `fn add_iter<I: Iterator<Item = T>>`

Comment: Thanks, @Shepmaster!
Is it possible with `where` also?

Comment: Yes: `fn add_iter<I>(&mut self, iter: I) where I: Iterator<Item = T>`.